# SQL Server 2008: most efficient way to empty the entire database without dropping the database

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please provide an efficient way to empty the entire database without dropping it.

Comment: Do you mean emptying all the tables? Or dropping all the tables?

Answer (score 0):

create a script that truncates the tables you need to clear.

Truncate Table [TableName]

you also have to consider the relationships between the tables